# Passing parameter to Excel's Range.Value(RangeValueDataType) in win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I'm trying to get the interior colours of a range of cells in Excel using win32com/python. Looping through each cell is not an option as that takes 3 to 5 seconds to complete while the colours change every second.

Using [Range.Value(11)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlrangevaluedatatype-enumeration-excel) seems like it can help, but win32com doesn't like it when any parameters are passed to Range.Value.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.Dispatch('excel.application')

fileName = r"myFile.xlsm"
myBook = excel.Workbooks(fileName)
mySheet = myBook.Sheets('Sheet1')
myRange = mySheet.Range('I3:AL32')

myState = myRange.Value # is acceptable but useless
myState = myRange.Value(11) # TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Executing myRange("I3:AL32").Value(11) in VBA within Excel works just fine, but I cannot create a custom UDF and use Application.Run from within win32com either because there is already VBA code running inside the base Excel file (which is what's changing the cell colours in the first place).

Is there another way to pass that parameter into Range.Value?

Comment: Not sure how this is going to work with a single-threaded Excel UI process if you are trying this at the same time as your VBA is executing.

Comment: There is a DoEvents in the VBA loop which colours the cells. For now I've just put in a Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A1") = myRange.Value(11) after that DoEvents, to then have win32com pick up the output from that makeshift helper cell. This is working, but I didn't want to add a VBA line. Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was playing around with this myself and I found an answer that will work with win32com

I used myRange._print_details_() to show what is accessible from the com object and I got the following:

```
Methods:
     GetValue
     SetValue
Props:
Get Props:
    Value = 0x6 - <win32com.client.build.MapEntry object at 0x00000184975AA160>
Put Props:
    Value = 0x6 - <win32com.client.build.MapEntry object at 0x00000184975AA1D0>
```

So from I can tell Value is a proptery that allows you to get or set the value using myRange.value

But there is also a GetValue and SetValue...

So instead of myRange.Value(11).. you want to use:

```
myRange.GetValue(11) # you can now pass the paramter to get xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it is the result you want and unfortunately it is not using win32com.client but comtypes.client, but if you try:

```
import comtypes.client # unfortunately not win32com
excel = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Excel.Application')

fileName = r"myFile.xlsx" # I used .xlsx but should work with .xlsm
myBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
mySheet = myBook.Sheets('Sheet1')
myRange = mySheet.Range('I3:AL32')

myState = myRange.Value(11) #with comtypes.client you can use the parameter 11
print myState
```

You print something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
......
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s21">
   <Interior ss:Color="#00B0F0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s23">
   <Interior ss:Color="#E26B0A" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s25">
   <Interior ss:Color="#00FF00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s26">
   <Interior ss:Color="#C0504D" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s27">
   <Interior ss:Color="#60497A" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
......
```

where you can find the codes for the different colors I used in my example.
Hope it is useful for you even if it is not with win32com.